# How can I write a Python function that loops through a list of dataframes and drops duplicate rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a "Main" dataframe which is being continuously built. Each month I merge new data into that one, however I want to remove rows that exist in both dataframes.

**Example "Main"**

| Name | Date | Begin Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 03/10/2022 | 11:04 | 14:10 |
| Dirk | 05/12/2022 | 13:15 | 16:56 |
| Steve | 01/13/2022 | 11:11 | 13:13 |

**"Other"**

| Name | Date | Begin Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rog | 03/14/2022 | 11:44 | 14:30 |
| Dirk | 05/12/2022 | 13:15 | 16:56 |
| Steve | 01/13/2022 | 11:11 | 13:13 |

**Expected Result**

| Name | Date | Begin Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 03/10/2022 | 11:04 | 14:10 |
| Rog | 03/14/2022 | 11:44 | 14:30 |

So far I have been able to accomplish this in a messy way, but there has to be a neater way to do this...

```
def merger(month, month2):
   a = pd.merge(df1, month, how = 'left', indicator = True)
   a = a[a['_merge'] != 'both'].drop('_merge', axis = 1)
   b = pd.merge(a, month2, how = 'left', indicator = True)
   b = b[b['_merge'] != 'both'].drop('_merge', axis = 1)
   return b
```

It's hideous and I have to keep adding to the function as each month arrives, but I am fairly new to Python and coding in general. Ideally I would like to write a function that loops through a list of dataframes as I can have up to 12 months at a time. It is important that it removes rows where the indicator = 'both' before merging the next dataframe.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this can be handled easily with `df.drop_duplicates`:
Thanks to @Mustafa Aydın for reminding `keep=False`

```
new_df = pd.concat([main, other])
new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

In my opinion, `pd.concat` suits better here as you can concat as many dataframes as you want:

```
larger_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: `pd.drop_duplicates` doesn't exist and you need `keep=False`

Comment: Thanks, I meant `df.drop_duplicates`. Btw, `keep=False` drop all duplicates but OP still wants to keep one occurence of them.

Comment: when i look at the expected output i see otherwise

Comment: oh okay, my bad thanks to @MustafaAydın. It should be `keep=False`

Comment: @brandooo23 `reset_index` before drop_duplicates is dangerours. `drop_duplicates` without column arg considers all columns; if the indices were different for rows for which other data were equal, they won't be dropped. either don't reset_index or give `drop_duplicates` a narrow subset of columns to look for dupes

Comment: So drop_duplicates is not considering index? I only want to drop rows where each column's value is a duplicate. The current index is an arbitrary number set by pandas.

Comment: @brandooo23 No, `drop_duplicates` doesn't care about index, it only drop duplicates whether indexes are the same or not